# Advanced Installer- Registry entry not added

Tags: windows-installer, exe, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced Installer to package my application. I added Registry entry under Registry Page of advanced installer, my problem is after my application is installed when I checked the registry (regedit) I can't find the key that I added. These are the places I looked into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` , `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are looking in the right places, for example a 32-bit setup will create its entries in the WoW6432Node registry on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks- found it, I should have known.